# Como colocar tag html id com nome variável usando razor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

Oi, galera.

Uma dúvida bem boba, mas tá me dando muita dor de cabeça...

Tenho esse trecho de código html usando razor em asp net mvc, quero mesclar o id  desse trecho, tipo, "nomedoid + codigo que varia", como faço? Sei que é simples, mas não tô conseguindo...

```
 <td id='permiteCertificacao + "@relatorioDTO.Identificador"'>@relatorioDTO.Nome</td>
```

Obrigada!

Comment: já tentou remover a aspas duplas da sua varável c#? Por exemplo: `<td id='permiteCertificacao-@relatorioDTO.Identificador'>@relatorioDTO.Nome</td>`

Comment: Tentou usar o `@Html.Raw()`?

Comment: usei e funcionou!! vou atualizar meu post pra, de repente, puder ajudar alguém. Obrigada.

Comment: resolvi dessa forma: ` @Html.Raw("<td class='largura20' id='permiteCertificacao" + @relatorioDTO.Identificador + "'>" + @relatorioDTO.Nome + "</td>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade é realmente muito simples:

```js
<td id='@string.Format("permiteCertificacao{0}", relatorioDTO.Identificador)'>@relatorioDTO.Nome</td>
```

Comment: verdade, várias formas de fazer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente na sua view você pode fazer: `<td id="prefixoTag_@item.seuIdAqui">`

Segue um exemplo

Model

```
public class Fruta
{
    public int FrutaId { get; set; }
    public string NomeFruta { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var listaFruta = new List<Fruta>
        {
            new Fruta { FrutaId = 1, NomeFruta = "Pera" },
            new Fruta { FrutaId = 2, NomeFruta = "Uva" },
            new Fruta { FrutaId = 3, NomeFruta = "Maçã" },
            new Fruta { FrutaId = 4, NomeFruta = "Salada Mista" }
        };

        return View(listaFruta);
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Fruta>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
  <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
 </p>
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FrutaId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeFruta)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td id="prefixoTag_@item.FrutaId">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FrutaId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeFruta)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}